# How to assign class of html element to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript

I am passing a javascript variable "name" to the following function:

```
function addCategory(name){
    $("#myTable").append('<tr class=name><td>'+name+'</td><td><a onclick="" type="button" class="btn btn-xs" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i></a></td></tr>');

    $('#postcat')[0].reset();

    }
```

If the 'name' variable contains the value "general", I want the class name to be "general" and not name.

How should I do it?

Comment: This is invalid code, not full.

Comment: 5 downvotes and not a single comment that would help this user to clarify his question. And OBVIOUSLY it is not valid code, this user has a problem with it... omg what is wrong with people here...

Comment: @ankita do you always want the **value** of `name` to be a class or only when the **value** is `general` and in every other case the class should be `name`?

Comment: *...to be "general" and not name.* "name" as a string or as a variable `name`?

Comment: name is a javascipt variable. with my mode, name was being used as a string for the class name. I got the answer anyway, thanks. It was indeed a stupid question :P

Answer (score 2):

You can use the varialbe to class name like this

```
$("#myTable").append('<tr class="'+name+'"><td>'+name+'</td><td><a onclick=""         type="button" class="btn btn-xs" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i></a></td></tr>');
```

Comment: OP didn't ask about this. It's not a correct answer, how is it?.. That's why I've downvoted. /cc @Angelos

Comment: @nicael if you bothered to comment that it is not correct, then why not comment with why you think it is not correct?

Comment: Nope. **OP want the class to be the one which holds *name variable* only if it doesn't contain "general"**.

Comment: @nicael This is the exact solution I came up with as well, which I did not post because it was already posted. The OP asked for this exactly!

Comment: I've clarified, @Jurik.

Comment: "now suppose the name variable **contains the value "general". I want the class name to be general and not name**. How should I do it?"

Comment: `name.indexOf('general')<0?"name":"general"`

Comment: If OP wanted `class="general"` when `name="I am the general"` and `class="name"`in all other cases then this answer is wrong

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you need to wrap the class name in quotes:

```
    function addCategory(name){
        $("#myTable").append("<tr class=\"" + name + "\">"
                             + "<td>" + name + "</td>"
                             + "<td><a onclick=\"\""
                                   + " type=\"button\""
                                   + " class=\"btn btn-xs\">"
                                   + "<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-erase\">"
                                   + "</i></a></td></tr>");
        $('#postcat')[0].reset();
    }
```

However there are other issues like your anchor doesn't contain anything.

Once you have formatted it correctly then you can just replace 'name' with whatever you like.

Comment: I will agree with that, however the quotes were missing altogether.

Answer (score -1):

Make use of ternary operator.

In case you want the class literally be *name* if variable `name` doesn't contain "general", here's how you do it.

```
$("#myTable").append('<tr class="'+name.indexOf('general')<0?"name":"general"+'"><td>'+name+'</td><td><a on...
```

In case you want the class to contain the value of `name` variable if this variable doesn't contain "general", you just remove quotes around `"name"`:

```
$("#myTable").append('<tr class="'+name.indexOf('general')<0?name:"general"+'"><td>'+name+'</td><td><a on...
```

Comment: And now it's my time to wonder, why the downvotes, since my answer is correct.

Comment: @mpl As the question was a bit unclear in this aspect, edited again.

Comment: @Jurik So you absolutely ignored the words ***contains the value "general"***, right? I don't get what's happening with you all.

Comment: @Jurik It's your time to explain why my answer is incorrect :)

Comment: I believe your first answer is correct now. The last example will work if OP meant that if the `name` contains `"I am the general"` then he wants `class="general"`

Comment: @Jurik Yes, *contains*, not *equals*. All other answers suppose it is *equals*, though this was stated really clearly.

Comment: @Jurik I'm not suggesting not to ask OP. Indeed, it would be great if OP replies, but the other answers are still incorrect...